# Why can not I choose a PCL Project in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library, .net-standard, shared-project

At the moment of creating a new project, only shared project and standard .NET come out.

Before I could only choose shared project and PCL project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET Standard has replaced PCL. .NET Standard 2.0 now offers a larger API surface then before.

See: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/XamarinShow/Episode-37-NET-Standard-Libraries-with-Immo-Landwerth and https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/XamarinShow/Snack-Pack-25-New-NET-Standard-Mobile-App-Templates-in-Visual-Studio-2017